# convert website to webapp

Tags: web-applications, web

I have created single page web application using angular js and bootstrap, I wanto convert it to mobile app. Please tell me how to build mobile app from existing webapp. 
I am the front end devloper and dont have much knowlege about backend language. Please suggest me easier option to learn.

Below is the calculator web app I have developed.
PSBGit link:

https://github.com/waghanil87/Angular_scientific_calc/blob/master/calculator_app_v2.7z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tools like react native or phonegap or Xamarin if you want to be native to the platform (android / Apple). These are all front end focussed.

Comment: @Anilwagh Glad it worked! Was it difficult to implement? Also, could you accept me as answer then?